# lightning-components tag: syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request

For now, only the Apex tag highlights formatted code.

With the raise of the Lightning experience adoption, I saw a lot of questions lately only referring Lightning components developement.

So, some time, there is only HTML and Javascript code posted in the question.

Could it be possible to add syntax highlighting on the lightning-components tag? That would improve code readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the *Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/google/code-prettify))* to lang-html. Let me know if a different value makes more sense.

[image: Code Language: lang-html]

Comment: Awesome thanks ! We have our first sample [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192697/lightningtabset-with-dynamic-content-is-not-correctly-rendered) and it's great !